# Como hacer return desde la ultima llamada de una función recursiva

Tags: python, function, recursión

Primer post en esta gran web jejeje. Soy un autentico novato.

Tengo una duda que me ha surgido resolviendo el siguiente problema:

*Crear un programa que lea por teclado una cadena y un carácter, y reemplace todos los dígitos en la cadena por el carácter.
Ej: su clave es: 1540 y X debería devolver su clave es: XXXX*

Aunque se solucionarlo, estuve pensando en alguna manera de mejorar el código. La idea es que si introduces mas de un carácter de segundo argumento, el método .replace te va a dar un error. Metiendo un bucle while que se ejecute mientras el tamaño del carácter sea distinto de 1 podría obligar a que el input sea de tamaño 1. Pero no se por que meter un bucle no me gusta. Y pensé que con una función recursiva podría funcionar.

Algo así:

```
def caracter():
    x = input("Introduzca un único caracter: ")
    if len(x) == 1:
        return x
    else:
        caracter()

cadena = input("Introduzca una cadena: ")
caract = caracter()
for c in cadena:
    cadena = cadena.replace(c, caract)
print (f"La nueva cadena es {cadena}")
```

Y claro, no funciona. Me he dado cuenta que el output, digamos, del segundo ciclo no va a la primera llamada, si no a la segunda y que esta no recibe nada en la llamada de la función, por lo que el segundo output esta vacío...
Así que me gustaría saber si ese return de la función una vez que se haya autollamado puede salir directamente del ciclo sin pasar por todas las llamadas que no han recibido respuesta.

Espero haberme explicado y gracias de antemano.

(PD: igual es una duda estúpida o una pregunta sin sentido. Llevo poco tiempo y la verdad que es divertido jugar con estas opciones. No se trata de una duda que necesite resolver por trabajo, estudios o nada importante. Hago esto por pura diversión.)

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres que la función retorne algo, tienes que usar `return` (obvio)

```
def caracter():
    x = input("Introduzca un único caracter: ")
    if len(x) == 1:
        return x
    else:
        return caracter()
```

El retorno será simétrico con la llamada. Cada vez que entras a una función, debes salir de ella. No hay posibilidades de "saltarse" las invocaciones previas.

Pero hacer una función recursiva para eso no tiene sentido.

La solución iterativa es

```
def caracter():
    x = ""
    while len(x) != 1:
        x = input("Introduzca un único caracter: ")
    return x
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero, debo decir que la recursividad no me parece la manera más apropiada para manejar la validación de la entrada del usuario. Un ciclo parece mucho más adecuado.

Dicho esto, para responder a tu pregunta, lo que te está haciendo falta es devolver el valor de la llamada recursiva, es decir, en código:

```
def caracter():
    x = input("Introduzca un único caracter: ")
    if len(x) == 1:
        return x
    else:
        return caracter()
```

Esto, en la práctica, hará que se retorne el caracter introducido por el usuario en la última llamada a la función, pues en su camino de salida, todas las llamadas recursivas irán retornando ese valor al nivel anterior, hasta salir definitivamente de la función.